# Changing the product that an add to cart button is adding to cart

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid

I want to give the customer an option to get a free item on top. I am already having an upsell product in place so I can't just use an app to sort this out.

I was hoping that I could add another add to cart button to the product page that would add the free item to the cart if the customer decides to take it.

I found this code snippet to add another button to the product page:

```
 <form method="post" action="/cart/add">
             <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
             <input min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
             <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" />
        </form>
```

The issue is that it just ads the same product to cart as the main add to cart button on the page.
How do I make the button add another product to the page?
If someone could help me I would be super grateful. I have been trying to figure this out for two days now and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

It adds the same product because, this line of code ***product.variants.first.id***, provides it the same id for the product. If you want to use a different product, first get it using [all_products](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/89205510-how-to-use-all_products-in-a-shopify-theme) and then add Id. The updated code will look like

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ all_products["coffee-cup"].first_available_variant.id }}" />
    <input min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Do not forget to change the **coffee-cup** above to your upselling product handle.